# undefined reference to `std::basic_string<wchar_t,

Tags: android, sqlite, makefile, undefined-reference

I am trying to compile my c++ files using cygwin.
\Files are compiled but linking time errors occur
These kind of errors...

```
undefined reference to `std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::size() const'
```

and some more errors like

```
undefined reference to `sqlite3_mprintf'
undefined reference to `sqlite3_exec'
undefined reference to `sqlite3_free'
undefined reference to `sqlite3_free'
undefined reference to `sqlite3_free'
undefined reference to `sqlite3_exec'
```

please help me out?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add the code where you include the headers. And why did you tag this question with the android tag? Please clarify you question in general and add more information about the context.

Comment: I have written some code in c++ and there are many files of cpp and I am compiling those files. All files are compiled successfully but when it comes to create .so file (i.e shared library ) it is giving me such errors.. And want to use this .so file so that I can call methods from my android project using JNI.

Comment: can you post your linking commands?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the standard C++ library is not getting linked in. Are you linking your code with `g++`, `gcc` or `ld`? If using the first, that library gets linked in automatically, but not if you're using the other two.

For the errors about `sqlite3`, you need to add `-lsqlite3` to the link command (assuming you have it installed, of course).